# Facebook App Authorization popup not closing

Tags: facebook, popup, authorization

I have a web site that's set up as a facebook application.

When new users access the web site and click the login button, the "Authorize this application" popup appears and after authorizing the application instead of closing, the popup reloads the whole site insite itself.

Has anyone experienced this kind of problems before?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your app's settings:

Go to the Web Site tab and set the **Site URL** to something like *http://www.yourdomain.com/yourapp/* and the **Site Domain** to something like *yourdomain.com*

I had the exact same problem until 1 minute ago. This solved it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using incorrect api key (or api key that is not linked to this url).

Go to http://www.facebook.com/developers/ and check if all urls are pointing to the right locations, "Site Domain" is set. Check that you are using correct api key (or id) and secret key in your SDK.

Comment: I am using Correct API and SECRET keys.. all setings are OK as well. :S . The authorization is OK also. If I close manually the AUthorization popup and reload the original page I can continue browsing the site and logged into facebook. The problem is that after the first app auth, that darn popup just wont close and its refreshing the website inside it.

Comment: @Bathan When I provide api key from a different app it behaves in a similar way - reloads all site in a popup but facebook login is not working. If you are sure that all setting are correct then I am not sure what's wrong... The site is not on localhost, is it? Can you provide your `Api.init()`?